# How to use blender?

Tags: workflow

I came to know about this amazing software blender. And I am amazed after seeing the artworks from this software.

I downloaded it on my laptop & in no time I was overwhelmed to see its user interface. Can you suggest to me the resources on how to use blender because this software looks highly creative & with endless possibilities. Also, I do not have a powerful laptop but a normal intel powered processor. Can this handle this software and the best free resources to learn this amazing piece of software.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because there are a lot of resources and tutorials online, especially youtube, on how to get started with Blender :)

Comment: Begin with tutorials for beginners, for example watch Grant Abbitt's tutos. You don't need a powerful computer at the beginning, plus Eevee is really fast

Comment: Start here, where many users start - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nIoXOplUvAw